# Export variable declared in script.sh and Import the value in mupltiple Makefiles

Tags: shell, makefile, permissions, sh

I am trying to create something like a global variable that I will use in order to make my project easy to deploy for other developers.
I would like to have an .sh file where there is a variable defining the location of the project.
Later on I want to export this variable and make it accessable in every makefile that I am creating so that I can use this design to keep everything constant and in one place.

This is an example of what I am trying to build:

Creating and exporting the variables in script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY='some path value here'
```

Importing the values in multiple Makefiles:

```
# start script and fetch the value
VAR := $(shell ./script.sh | sed -n '/^result: /s/^.*: //p')

all:
    @echo VAR=$(VAR)
```

I would like to see how other people are dealing with the same problem.
Being a better developer is my goal here. :)

Feedback always welcomed.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables exported in the shell are visible from make, so in a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR=value
export VAR

make $*
```

The Makefile will start with `VAR` defined to `value`.  That's one way to get variables from a shell script into make.

If you don't want the shell script to run make, you can have a user source it:

```
$ source script.sh
$ make
```

The variables set in the script will be visible to make this way too.

Or course there doesn't seem to be any reason you need a shell script here.  Stick your configuration into a fragment of a Makefile (which would look almost *exactly* like your shell script, but not use quotes for multiple word values) and then `include Makefile.inc` in your main makefile.

Also note that syntax like this:

```
#!/bin/sh or another commment
VAR=value
export VAR
```

It equally valid included in a Makefile or sourced into a shell script.  So sometimes it's possible to use the same include file in both places!